# how to read files saved on the server using php and make a call to that php page using ajax to display the list of files

Tags: php, ajax

how to rad the names of all files saved in the folder on the server using php.
and then make a call to that php page using ajax to display that list of files

Comment: You do realize that this is read by actual real people, don't you?

Answer (score 0):

This is the code to display file list:

```
$dir   = '/tmp'; // your directory path
$files = scandir($dir);

foreach ($files as $file)
{
  if (is_file($file))
  {
    echo $file . '<br />';
  }
}
```

This is the HTML/JavaScript to display the file list (if you use jQuery which is highly advised):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>File list</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      $("#content").load('<your listing PHP URL>');
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```