# How to do get using jquery ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to read files saved on the server using php and make a call to that php page using ajax to display the list of files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5443640/how-to-read-files-saved-on-the-server-using-php-and-make-a-call-to-that-php-page)

How to get contents from XML file stored on the server using first PHP, to get list of files, then using `$.ajax` GET method to get the contents from that XML file.

Comment: Also, why do you keep asking the same question over and over?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5443640/how-to-read-files-saved-on-the-server-using-php-and-make-a-call-to-that-php-page#question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5463456/how-to-get-the-contents-from-php-page-to-the-javascript-page-using-ajax

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'returnXML.php',
  dataType: 'xml',
  success: function(data) {
  //Whatever you want to do with that data.
  }
});
```